# folder and file creation not working

Tags: java, runtime-error, ioexception

I am currently having trouble creating a folder and a file if not present. I keep getting and error about it not being specified and I don't really know how to fix it.

this is my main

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        timeKeepHome ja = new timeKeepHome();
        //ja.setVisible(true);
        fileTimeLog log = new fileTimeLog();


        log.checkFile();

    }

}
```

and this is my class to create the file/ folder.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Formatter;


public class fileTimeLog 
{
    File log = new File("log/sixWeek.dat");
    File folder = new File("log");
    PrintWriter logW = new PrintWriter("log/sixWeek.dat");

    public fileTimeLog() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("successful");
        checkFile();
    }

    public void checkFile() throws IOException
    {
        if(!(log.exists()))
        {
            createFile();

        }
    }
    public void saveTime() throws IOException
    {

    }

    public void saveDate()
    {

    }

    public void createFile() throws IOException
    {
        folder.mkdir();
        logW = new PrintWriter(log);
        logW.println("DONT MODIFY THIS FILE IF UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOUR ARE DOING ");
        logW.close();

    }

}
```

and the error i'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: log\sixWeek.dat (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:184)
    at fileTimeLog.<init>(fileTimeLog.java:17)
    at main.main(main.java:18)
```

I would make everything look nicer and neater but I'm just really frustrated and I've done research but don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

The `Printwriter` will try and create a file, so when you do this

```
 PrintWriter logW = new PrintWriter("log/sixWeek.dat");
```

in your class defintion, then it will try to create it, but the folder does not exist until you do `createFile`

As you re-initialize `logW` in `createFile` anyway, you do not need to initialize it in your class defintion